# Can TortoiseGit and GitHub for Windows client coexist?

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

Just wondering if there's anyone out there with both TortoiseGit and the GitHub Windows client (["GitHub for Windows"](http://windows.github.com/)) installed on the same machine that can confirm that they can peacefully coexist.  I am on Windows 7 x64 and already have TortoiseGit installed which integrates into the file system fairly deeply since it's an explorer extension.  I'm hesitant to mess anything up by installing another Git client on top of it and I don't want to have to uninstall TortoiseGit.

Comment: I know that msysgit and GitHub Windows can coexist peacefully, so at the very least it is possible to have multiple git installations on one system. Definitely want to make sure that you choose *not* to update your path when installing Github Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They don't interfere in any way

Comment: They do, TortoiseGit steals GitHub Desktop links (configures itself as default).